# MySQL perform commands on list of table names

Tags: mysql, sql, loops

I have a list of table names which I would like loop through to perform commands on like `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`ALTER`. I have tried with no luck so far. How do I do this? Here is how I would like it to function.

```
-- A variable list of table names
set @table_names = 'table1,table2,table2';
-- Value to insert
set @mydata = 1;
-- Loop through the names
[How do I do the loop?]
  -- Perform SQL Commands like
  INSERT into table_name (data) VALUES (@mydata);
[End Loop]
```

Thanks!

Comment: I've always used a second language to generate the sql.  Like perl/php/python.

Comment: It is easiest to do this in a programming language since loops are a main part of their syntax.  For mysql take a look at dynamic sql and cursors.  Let me know if there is another language you can use other than sql.

Comment: Thanks - I was seeing if we could do this with pure sql so we could run a sql script on each of database servers.